# Can other members of a Quidditch team catch the snitch?

Tags: harry-potter

If another member of a Quidditch team catches the snitch, does it count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a foul in Quidditch called a **Snitchnip**. It's defined as

> *Any player other than Seeker touching or catching the Golden Snitch*
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch Through the Ages](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages_(real))</sup></sub>

The implication is that interfering with the Snitch can cost you a *personal penalty*...

> The referee may award penalties against a team. The Chaser taking the
> penalty will fly from the central circle towards the scoring area. All
> players other than the opposing Keeper must keep well back while the
> penalty is taken.
>
> <sub><sup>[Quidditch Through the Ages](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Quidditch_Through_the_Ages_(real))</sup></sub>

...but not a sending off.

> Down in the stands, Dean Thomas was yelling, ‘Send him off, ref! Red
> card!’ **‘This isn’t football, Dean,’ Ron reminded him. ‘You can’t send
> people off in Quidditch** – and what’s a red card?’
>
> ...
>
> ‘All right, all right. Flint nearly kills the Gryffindor Seeker, which
> could happen to anyone, I’m sure, so a penalty to Gryffindor, taken by
> Spinnet, who puts it away, no trouble, and we continue play,
> Gryffindor still in possession.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

Comment: Yeah, but what does that mean? Is the game over, does anyone get points?

Comment: @Gallifreian If it's a foul, it counts as nothing except a penalty to the player.

Comment: Surely someone catches the Snitch, gets told off and has to let it go again? Penalty awarded and play resumes. This being a rule, it probably happens very rarely. You just wouldn't touch the Snitch. And other players are quite busy!

Comment: @ThruGog - That seems to be the size of it. Note that this is likely to muck with the "sense memory" of the snitch. A new snitch may need to be brought it.

Comment: @Valorum - Yes I think you're right. Aren't they only supposed to be handled with gloves before the match?

Comment: @ThruGog - Yes, in competition matches.